# Apply image hover effects and functionality to an PSD image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, psd

I am working with a layered PSD image and I need to apply hover effects and functionality on it. I have seen a few examples using the HTML map and exact coordinates, but I don't have these coordinates or at least I'm not currently aware of how to get them.

Any ideas? It's pretty much [this functionality](http://jsfiddle.net/sb9j7/) without having coordinates.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it visually with dreamweaver (just the map link area)

other [tools](http://code.google.com/p/imgmap/) (download desktop adobe-air version)

Answer (score 1):

HTML map works with pixel (but you call them coordinates). Imagine a 100px * 100px image. If you divide that image in 4 imaginary scuares, each one should be 25px *25px.
No, imagine you want to map the upper left square, you just need to write the "coordinates", witch are (0, 0, 25, 25).
That is, from the 0px from left to right, and the 0px from top to bottom, to the 25px from left to right and to the 25px from the top to the bottom.